# How to update GCE image with the same name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I use GCE image to save my environments which I want to use repeatedly.

I want to update the content of the images when I made changes to the environments, like I do with Docker image using tag .

But when I execute `gcloud compute images create` when the image with same name exists, it raises an error:

```
$ gcloud compute images create image_name --source-disk updated-gce-instance \
    --source-disk-zone us-central1-c --family ubuntu-1604-lts

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/my_project/global/images/image_name' already exists
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Do I have to delete the image before updating, or name it like `image_name-20190225` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a new image with the same name of already existing Google Compute Engine image instance. In order to use the same name, you will have first to delete the image instance and then create a new one. For more information about how to manage Google Compute Engine images, you can find at [Image Management Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/image-management-best-practices) documentation.

However, after creating one, you can modify the already existing image from Google Console. Go to `Compute Engine > Images` pages and choose your created image. Click on `Edit` and then you will see that you can only modify the Labels of that image. You can add a startup script that will be executed when the image is created. You can use the `startup-script` key and run the commands in the `Value` field or use the `startup-script-url` key and write the `Google Cloud Storage URL` in the value. For more information you can visit the [Running Startup Scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) documentation.

Comment: Plus one. Thank you. Gracias for the brilliant content. Congrats.